# Why does my dll compiled with Visual-C++ have no entry points?

Tags: c, visual-c++, dll

I'm just trying to figure out how to call C code from C#.

I have the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void print(const char *message)
{
   printf("%s\\n", message);
}
```

I compile this with:

```
cl /LD printf.c
```

That produces a dll. But

```
dumpbin /exports printf.dll
```

shows no entry point:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.23918.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file printf.dll
File Type: DLL

Summary

    2000 .data
    1000 .gfids
    7000 .rdata
    1000 .reloc
   10000 .text
```

And trying to call it from C# turns up an EntryPointNotFoundException (I import it like this:)

```
[DllImport("printf.dll", EntryPoint = "print")]
static extern void print(string message);
```

So what am I missing here?

Comment: You did not tell the linker that it needed to be exported, `extern` does not do anything useful since that's the default.  Use `__declspec(dllexport)` instead.  Or a .def file.  Or the linker's /EXPORT option.

Comment: @Hans Thanks if you were to post that as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Fairly sure you know everything you need to complete this Q+A yourself.  Do keep in mind that we already have a lot of existing Q+A about this, fairly doubtful your addition would be a useful one.